# CppUnit Linking error with Clang on Mac OS X

Tags: c++, macos, linker, clang, cppunit

I am trying to compile a test program using CppUnit.  The problem is, with this sample code:

```
//[...]

class EntityComponentTest : public CppUnit::TestFixture
{
CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE( EntityComponentTest );
CPPUNIT_TEST( testGetComponents );
CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE_END();
Entity e;


public:
void setUp(){
    e.addComponent("1", new TestComponent("Hello 1"));
    e.addComponent("2", new TestComponent("Hello 2"));
}

void tearDown(){}

void testGetComponents()
{
    TestComponent &first = static_cast<TestComponent&>(e.getComponent("1"));
    TestComponent &second = static_cast<TestComponent&>(e.getComponent("2"));

    CPPUNIT_ASSERT(first.msg == "Hello 1");
    CPPUNIT_ASSERT(second.msg == "Hello 2");

}


};
CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE_REGISTRATION( EntityComponentTest );
int main(void)
{
//followed from tutorial
CppUnit::TextUi::TestRunner run;
CppUnit::TestFactoryRegistry &r = CppUnit::TestFactoryRegistry::getRegistry();
run.addTest(r.makeTest());

run.run("", false, true);

return 0;
}
```

I am getting the linking error:

```
  Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "CppUnit::SourceLine::SourceLine(std::__1::basic_string<char,    std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int)", referenced from:
  EntityComponentTest::testGetComponents() in EntityComponentTest.cpp.o
  "CppUnit::TextTestRunner::run(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>,   std::__1::allocator<char> >, bool, bool, bool)", referenced from:
  _main in EntityComponentTest.cpp.o
  "CppUnit::TestFactoryRegistry::getRegistry(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
  _main in EntityComponentTest.cpp.o
  CppUnit::AutoRegisterSuite<EntityComponentTest>::AutoRegisterSuite() in   EntityComponentTest.cpp.o
  "CppUnit::Message::Message(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>,  std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>,  std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
  EntityComponentTest::testGetComponents() in EntityComponentTest.cpp.o
 "CppUnit::TestCase::TestCase(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
  CppUnit::TestCaller<EntityComponentTest>::TestCaller(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, void (EntityComponentTest::*)(), EntityComponentTest*) in EntityComponentTest.cpp.o
 "CppUnit::TestSuite::TestSuite(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >)", referenced from:
  EntityComponentTest::suite() in EntityComponentTest.cpp.o
 "CppUnit::TestSuiteBuilderContextBase::getTestNameFor(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) const", referenced from:
  EntityComponentTest::addTestsToSuite(CppUnit::TestSuiteBuilderContextBase&) in EntityComponentTest.cpp.o
 "CppUnit::Test::findTestPath(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, CppUnit::TestPath&) const", referenced from:
  vtable for CppUnit::TestCaller<EntityComponentTest> in EntityComponentTest.cpp.o
 "CppUnit::Test::resolveTestPath(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) const", referenced from:
  vtable for CppUnit::TestCaller<EntityComponentTest> in EntityComponentTest.cpp.o
 "CppUnit::Test::findTest(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) const", referenced from:
  vtable for CppUnit::TestCaller<EntityComponentTest> in EntityComponentTest.cpp.o
 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am using the -lcppunit flag when invoking clang.  When I run the make file on my Linux machine, it compiles fine.

```
libcppunit-1.12.1.0.0.dylib
libcppunit-1.12.1.dylib
libcppunit.a
libcppunit.dylib
```

Are in my /usr/local/lib/.  I even tried installing to /usr/lib and the same linking error occurs.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks very much!

EDIT:  I figured out the problem.  I am using libc++ since I am using std::shared_ptr in my project.  Problem is that I tried compiling CppUnit with libc++ but it throws linking errors.  It seems it must be compiled with libstdc++, which would require me to install Fink or Macports so I could install the latest version of gcc and libstdc++.  I really hope to avoid this since there will be a whole mess trying to set it up.  I really also hope to avoid using Boost for the shared_ptr.

Is any of this possible?  If not I'll probably give in and install MacPorts

Comment: When you solve your own problem, post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue. It's OK after setting "C++ Standard Library" as "libstdc++(GNU C++ standard library)".